# How to cache the data pulled from BigQuery in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a webapp that pulls data from BigQuery into my Django views, which then will be passed as a context to the frontend templates. However, this data pulling process will occur initially when I open the web, and will occur again everytime I refresh the page. Is there a way I can cache the data I have pulled?

My `views.py` code looks similarly to this:

```py
def index(request):
    client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset_id = "project-id.dataset-id"
    tables = client.list_tables(dataset_id)
    tables_list = [table.table_id for table in tables]

    data_list = []
    for table_id in tables_list:
         query_string = f"""
              SELECT *
              FROM `project-id.dataset-id.{table_id}`
         """
    
         query_job = (
              client.query(query_string)
              .result()
         )

         records = [dict(row) for row in query_job]
         data_list.extend(records)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
    ...
    # Data manipulation syntax here using pandas dataframe
    ...
    data_json = df.to_json(orient="records")

    context = {'data_json': data_json}

    return render(request, 'template_name', context)
```

I passed the data as a JSON to the context because I'm passing it to a React frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are many way to cache data in Django, here i'll show you the most fast and efficient one [according to Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/topics/cache/) : **memcached**

1. **Download and Install memcached :** If you are on Linux, download from https://memcached.org/downloads.
   `./configure && make && sudo make install` to install.
   After installing Memcached, open a shell and start it using the following command: `memcached -l 127.0.0.1:11211`
2. **Install a python bindings :** After installing Memcached, you have to install its Python bindings. You cane use [pymemcache](https://pypi.org/project/pymemcache/), `pip install pymemcache`.
3. **Add memcached settings to your project :**

   ```
   CACHES = {
     'default': {
       'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyMemcacheCache',
       'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
     }
   }
   ```
4. **Cache levels :** Django provides the following levels of caching, listed here by ascending order of granularity:

- *Low-level cache API:* Provides the highest granularity. Allows you to cache specific queries or calculations.
- *Template cache:* Allows you to cache template fragments.
- *Per-view cache:* Provides caching for individual views.
- *Per-site cache:* The highest-level cache. It caches your entire site.

5. **Using Low-Level cache API in your example :**

**views.py**

```
from django.core.cache import cache

def index(request):
    # First, try to retrieve the cached data if exist
    cached_data_json = cache.get('cached_data_json')
    
    # If the data has not been cached yet, generate and cache it
    if not cached_data_json:
        client = bigquery.Client()
        dataset_id = "project-id.dataset-id"
        tables = client.list_tables(dataset_id)
        tables_list = [table.table_id for table in tables]

        data_list = []
        for table_id in tables_list:
          query_string = f"""
            SELECT *
            FROM `project-id.dataset-id.{table_id}`
          """

          query_job = (
            client.query(query_string)
            .result()
          )

       records = [dict(row) for row in query_job]
       data_list.extend(records)

       df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
       ...
       # Data manipulation syntax here using pandas dataframe
       ...
       data_json = df.to_json(orient="records")
       # Cache the data
       cache.set('cached_data_json', data_json)

    context = {'data_json': data_json}

    return render(request, 'template_name', context)
```

This is how it's work: if the `cached_data_json` is present in the cache then  use it, else, make a new computation and store it in the cache as `cached_data_json`.

**OPTIONAL :** You can use [django-memcache-status](https://pypi.org/project/django-memcache-status/) in order to monitor **Memcached**.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still kinda confused with the example that you gave. Doesn't that mean if the data actually exists in the cache, wouldn't that mean we pass the `cached_data_json` to the context instead of the `data_json`?

Comment: After trying it out, it turns out I'm right with the comment I have mentioned above. So I would alter the code into `data_json = cache.get('cached_data_json')` and then use the if condition `if not data_json:`, so that when the data_json is None, it will pull the data from the BQ and will be passed into the `context`. If it exists already, then the `data_json` will immediately be passed into the `context`.